# Why does the scatter plot of calculated determinants and traces using uniformly distributed inputs not look as expected?

Tags: python, numpy, random, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the probability for a linear system to be various types of stability, where the system is given by the following matrix:

[[a,b],
[c,d]]

And a,b,c,d are chosen from a random *uniform* distribution from a domain of [-1,1].
The primary graph of interest is trace vs. determinant, ie. (a+d) vs. (a*d-c*b)

[image: Plot of stability classification]

In my code I generate random matrices using numpy.random.uniform(-1,1,size(2,2)). The trace and determinant then have ranges of [-2,2]. Here is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

det = [] # determinant
tr = [] # trace
i=0

while i < 100000:
    linsys = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(2,2))
    tr.append(linsys[0][0]+linsys[1][1])
    det.append(linsys[0][0]*linsys[1][1]-linsys[1][0]*linsys[0][1])
    i += 1
    
print(np.max(tr),np.max(det),np.min(tr),np.min(det))
    
plt.scatter(det,tr)
plt.title("Plot of Trace v Determinant")
plt.xlabel("a*d-c*b")
plt.ylabel("a+d")
#plt.scatter(np.abs(det),2*np.sqrt(np.abs(det)))
#plt.scatter(np.abs(det),-2*np.sqrt(np.abs(det)))

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize =(6, 4))
ax1.hist(det, bins = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
plt.title('Histogram of trace')
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize =(6, 4))
ax2.hist(trace, bins = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
plt.title('Histogram of determinant')
```

I'd expect the graph of trace vs. determinant to be completely uniform with no weird shapes but instead I find this very strange shape when plotting them:

[image: Plot of trace v determinant]

And these are the distributions of the trace and determinant:

[image: ![Distributions of trace and determinant]

Again, since all the variables a,b,c,d have the same domain [-1,1] I'd expect the sum of them or products of them to still have a uniform distribution. I'm wondering then why there's this strange shape in the scatter plot of trace v determinant then? Maybe I am defining the uniformly random matrix incorrectly?

Comment: You aren't plotting the output of numpy.random.uniform, so your premise is flawed.

Comment: Sum/product of uniformly distributed variables won't be uniformly distributed, though.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think the sum or products of these uniform distributions should still be uniform since a,b,c,d are all from the same domain [-1,1], therefore at the very least the distributions of the trace and determinant should be uniform but they're not

Comment: @LeviRamsey Apologies - I thought they would be in this case since a,b,c,d are all pulled from the same domain [-1,1]?

Comment: @jay, the PDF of distribution of the product of two samples from  U[-1, -1] is a triangle distribution on [-2, 2]--it is the convolution of U[-1,1] with itself.  If you increase the number of bins in the plot of the histogram of the trace, you should be able to see the triangle.  The PDF of the distribution of the product  `x = u1*u2` where `u1` and `u2` are two samples from U[-1, 1] is -log(abs(x))/2.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you! Yeah as I was reading around more I realised that I was wrong

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: the PDF of distribution of the **sum** of two samples from U[-1, -1] is a triangle distribution on [-2, 2].